# Socket.io keeps on making new connection to single brower and ends in JavaScript heap out of memory?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, socket.io

I am making a stock app with a stock watchlist , but the socket.io clients keeps on making new connection to a single browser. After about 250 connection it gives the javascript heap out of memory and stops working.The data that i am sending from socket is an array of objetc similar to the one in the initial state in the client side code. Also if you have a better way to render it and any other suggestion that would be nice.

**Server Side**

```
       const express = require('express');
       const socketio = require('socket.io');
       const http = require('http');
       const User = require('./model/stock.js')

       require('./db/mongoose.js')

       const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;

      //const router = require('./router') 

       const app = express();
       const server = http.createServer(app);
       const io = socketio(server);



       io.on('connection',(socket) => {
       console.log('New connection')



       const Watchlist=['3MINDIA','SBIN','GLENMARK']
       setInterval(( )=> {


    //Gives localtime with seconds always 00 
    var d = new Date();
    var timeStamp = d.toLocaleTimeString('en-US', { hour12: false });
    const lac =timeStamp.slice(0,6)
    const localtime = lac+"00"

    //Finding all stocks with time equal to localtime (minutedata)
    User.find({ time : localtime},(err, res) =>{  

        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        }
        //Pushing all the stock matching the stocks in watchlist into an array Allstock and emitting 
        it 
        //Repeating it every Second              
        const AllStocks=[]     
        Watchlist.map(watch =>{
            res.map(stock =>{
                if(stock.symbol == watch){
                    let obj ={
                        symbol:stock.symbol,
                        price:stock.close
                    }
                    list.push(obj)

                }
            })
        })
      socket.emit('stock',AllStocks)

    })
     },1000)


   })



   server.listen(PORT, ()=> console.log(`Server is running on port ${PORT}`))
```

**Client Side**

```
enter code here
import React, { useEffect,useState } from 'react';
import './sidebar.css'
import io from 'socket.io-client';

function SideDrawer (props) {

let drawerClass = "side-drawer"
if(props.show === 'watchlist'){
    drawerClass = "side-drawer open"
}

//Intial state are random values
const [Stock, setStock] = useState([{symbol:'SBIN', price:'125'},{symbol:'3MINDIA', price:'1254'}]);
let socket;
const ENDPOINT = 'localhost:5000';
socket= io(ENDPOINT);


 useEffect(()=>{

   socket.on('stock', (res)=>{
        setStock(res)
    })    
})

return(
<nav className={drawerClass} >
    <ul className="side-bar">
    <div>
  {Stock.map((item) => (
    <li key={item.symbol} >{item.symbol} = {item.price}</li> 
  ))}
</div>
    </ul>
</nav>
)}

export default SideDrawer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have forgotten dependency in your useEffect. You want to set this listener only on first render (componentDidMount), your useEffect should look like this:

```
 useEffect(()=>{

   socket.on('stock', (res)=>{
        setStock(res)
    })    
}, [])
```

Without this, useEffect is fired on every render, and because you setStock with every render, this fires next render - and the app get's in cycle.

Comment: After adding dependency , it doesnt show heap error but still keeps on making new connections but at slower speed. And with each new connection the execution time also increases

Comment: And againg got the same eror of javascript heap after some time